# Realm models' relationships - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have 2 Realm models that should be connected to each other but I have difficulty understanding how to do this when writing to a model.

The 1st model will always be populated before the 2nd. This model contains a course name and some data related to the course:

```
class CourseModel: Object {

    dynamic var coursename = ""
    dynamic var par3field = 0
    dynamic var par4field = 0
    dynamic var par5field = 0
}
```

The second model has all the scoring data related to the course:

```
class ScoresModel: Object {

    dynamic var dateplayed = ""
}
```

My question is this - how do i write the ScoresModel data and link this data to the appropriate CourseModel's course name and it's associated data?

ADDITIONAL AFTER ANSWER FROM bcamur:
bcamur, thank you for the feedback. This looks like what I need. However, when writing the ScoresModel to Realm, what do i need to do to let the Realm know to which course name to link the ScoresModel data I just wrote?

I'm currently writing the 2 models like this:

```
let mycourse = CourseModel()
        mycourse.coursename = courseName
        mycourse.par3field = par3s
        mycourse.par4field = par4s
        mycourse.par5field = par5s
        CoursesData.addNewCourse(my course)

let dataToSave = ScoresModel()
        dataToSave.dateplayed = dateTextField.text!
        ScoresData.saveNewScores(dataToSave)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will your CourseModel have only 1 ScoresModel or more than 1?

Comment: The CourseModel will have many ScoresModels. I'm checking that course names are not duplicated, there can only be one. So for every round played a new ScoreModel is saved for the course. I hope that's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the `ScoresModel` objects as a list in your `CourseModel`:

```
class CourseModel: Object {
    dynamic var coursename = ""
    dynamic var par3field = 0
    dynamic var par4field = 0
    dynamic var par5field = 0

    let scoreModels: List<ScoresModel> = List<ScoresModel>()
}

class ScoresModel: Object {
    dynamic var dateplayed = ""

    //include this if you want to be able to see which course has this ScoresModel in its scoresModels list
    var courseModel: CourseModel? {
        return linkingObjects(CourseModel.self, forProperty: "scoreModels").first
    }
}
```

Comment: bcamur, thank you for the feedback. This looks like what I need. However, when writing the ScoresModel to Realm, what do i need to do to let the Realm know to which course name to link the ScoresModel data I just wrote?

Comment: You can create the ScoresModel and append it to the scoreModels list in a write transaction and Realm will handle the rest.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this bcamur. Do I need to do something like this? let myCourse = NewCourse(); myCourse.coursename = courseName; dataToSave.scoreModels.append(myCourse)

Comment: No, you should do something like this: let myCourse = NewCourse(); myCourse.coursename = "A New Course"; let myScoreModel = NewScoreModel(); myCourse.scoreModels.append(myScoreModel);  After doing this your ScoreModel will be saved in your CourseModel. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes this makes sense. Herein lies my issue, I do not want to create "A New Course". When a user starts using the app they add course details and every time they play the course they then enter the scores data for the course played. So I do not want to add a new course every time I write new scores, I only want to link the scores to the course already in the course Model. Is this different from what you describe above?

Comment: I see, if I were you I would define a `coursename` as primary key for the CourseModel like this:  `override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "coursename"
    }` and then use it to fetch the CourseModel that the user played from Realm like this: `let course = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(CourseModel.self, key: "someCoursename")` and then add the new score to the course you fetched from Realm like this:  `course.scoreModels.append(newlyPlayedScoreModel)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108232/discussion-between-cor-brink-and-bcamur).